# libvlccore8:amd64 3.0.0 broken link in artful

Tags: apt, upgrade, vlc

By the way, *libvlccore8* is used in many packages and cannot be purged. On the other hand, the running version (which works fine) is 2.2.6 (as shown below).

So, my question is: how do I tell the system that there is no need to upgrade *libvlccore8* from 2.2.6 to 3.anything?

```
root@www:~# apt list --upgradable
En train de lister... Fait
libvlccore8/artful 3.0.0~~git20171210+r73147+99~ubuntu17.10.1 amd64 [peut être mis à jour depuis : 2.2.6-6]
N: Il y a  1  version supplémentaire. Utilisez « -a » pour la voir
root@www:~# apt list --upgradable -a
En train de lister... Fait
libvlccore8/artful 3.0.0~~git20171210+r73147+99~ubuntu17.10.1 amd64 [peut être mis à jour depuis : 2.2.6-6]
libvlccore8/artful,now 2.2.6-6 amd64 [installé, peut être mis à jour vers : 3.0.0~~git20171210+r73147+99~ubuntu17.10.1]
```

PS: I use VLC 4.0.0 RC1 (which provides *libvlccore9*), which is much nicer than Parole.

Comment: libvlccore8 is only used by other vlc packages & the phonon backend. So if not needing the phonon packages then remove it.

Comment: Seems to concern "plasma5" and a few other ones:

Comment: Parts of phonon are installed, but not phonon it self (as shown with "apt search phonon | grep installé" & "apt search phonon | grep -i 'phonon/' " (answers are lots too long for here).

Comment: Looking for "phonon":
apt search phonon | grep installé | grep -v automatique => 
libphonon4qt5-4/artful,now 4:4.9.0-4 amd64  [installé]
python-qt4/artful,now 4.11.4+dfsg-2build2 amd64  [installé]

Comment: apt -s purge libvlccore8 => 
kactivitymanagerd khelpcenter kinit kio kpackagelauncherqml libkf5declarative5 libkf5khtml-bin libkf5khtml5 libkf5newstuff5 libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5notifications5
libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5parts-plugins libkf5parts5 libkf5plasma5 libkf5plasmaquick5 libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5wallet-bin libkf5wallet5 libkwalletbackend5-5 libvlccore8
phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-vlc plasma-framework qml-module-org-kde-kconfig qml-module-org-kde-kirigami qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons
qml-module-org-kde-newstuff

Comment: So I believe that libvlccore8 is useful and works fine, so no update is needed: I just need to tell it to the system (Ubuntu Studio 17.10 64-bit). Thanks for help :-)

Comment: Just because you believe it doesn't make it true. If desired look into apt-pinning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have enabled a PPA which provides an updated version of `libvlccore8`, but you want to stick to the official Ubuntu version. You can add a file like this in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` to decrease the priority of the PPA version:

```
Package: libvlccore8
Pin: origin "ppa.launchpad.net"
Pin-Priority: 99
```

Comment: Thanks. It works :-)
PS: I put the lines in a file named "libvlccore8" without any extension (NO .list or anything else required/allowed).

Comment: Still OK after reboot. Thanks. Where do I click to close le trouble? (or say it has been solved?)

Comment: I have been able/allowed to run "apt autoremove", which is usually automatic but (presumably) blocked by this issue. With the autoremove, 15 packages were seen partially configured ("15 partiellement installés") were finalized, including VLC itself (4.0.0~rc1~~git20171227+r73405+113~ubuntu17.10.1 VLC Daily Build of master branch:17.10/artful [amd64]).

Comment: I believe the preference trick might be of interest for people having similar issues. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @DigaMex You can [accept the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Not sure what I have to do to "accept the answer". Click on the grey "v" (which turned it to green) ? Please tell me whether it is Ok or not (as I am new here). Thanks :-)

Comment: Yes, the "grey 'v'" is called a check mark. ;)